# DLL Hell with Intel Redistributables

Tags: c++, windows, dll, manifest, redistributable

Some of our users have been complaining about a *libmmd.dll not found* error on our plugins loading.

Some background:

- I'm talking about an issue occurring on **Windows** (8, for that matter).
- We develop plugins for **Digital Audio Workstations** (for digital sound
  processing purposes).
- Our plugin is a **DLL** coded in VS2012 and compiled with **Intel Compiler 2015** via Perl scripts calling **icl.exe
  from the cmd**.
- One of its dependencies is an Intel-supplied math
  library provided in the **2015 flavor of its redistributables** (which we
  install together with our plugins) called **libmmd.dll**.

For a matter of convenience, let's call the plugin DLL **plugin.dll** (!!!).

I didn't have much time on one of the affected users' machine but from what I saw, reinstalling Intel's redistributables package didn't help, only moving libmmd.dll to the same folder as plugin.dll.

Whatever the reason for this (sudden and unexpected) behavior, we want to be able to deliver software protected against this kind of issues (**DLL Hell**).

What we want is for **plugin.dll to look for libraries first in a specific directory** (configurable would be even better), then in its usual [search order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx).

I tried playing with **manifests**, **registry**, **library names**, **linker options**...
The only things that actually worked were switching the **/MD option with /MT** (but recompiling with static libs really adds to the size of plugin.dll) and copying the library to the folder plugin.dll is in.

Any ideas ?
Thanks !

Comment: /MT is quite reasonable for plugins.  The size growth is just perception, you have to measure the /MD size by summing the size of all the dependencies.  Never less than the /MT size.  The odds that you can share an /MD dependency with another process are never that good.  And causes DLL Hell.

Answer (score 0):

The [`SetDllDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203(v=vs.85).aspx) function lets you add a folder path to the DLL search order. It will be added in second place, immediately behind the program folder itself.

This only affects DLLs loaded via `LoadLibrary` however; if your DLLs are loaded statically it won't make any difference.